# Problemas con menú en bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

Tengo un problema con el menú cuando scrollea, resulta que hay un signo "+" que muestra mas contenido del menú entonces cuando uno vuelve hacia arriba el menú queda fijo abierto y debería desaparecer O bien cerrarse solo, como podría hacerlo? 
hay una clase llamada "open"

```js
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 360) {
    $("#on-scroll").css('top', '0');
  } else {
    $("#on-scroll").css('top', '-150px');
  }
});
```

```css
.bootstraps #menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 15px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-image: transparent;
}

.bootstraps .menu-principal {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-family: 'Univers';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  float: right;
}

.bootstraps .navbar-default .menu-principal a {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.bootstraps .navbar-default .menu-principal>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: initial;
}

.bootstraps .navbar-default .menu-principal>li>a:hover {
  color: #ffd100;
  text-shadow: initial;
}

.bootstraps .navbar-default .menu-principal>.active>a {
  background-color: initial;
  background-image: initial;
  box-shadow: initial;
  color: #ffd100;
}

.bootstraps .navbar-default .menu-principal>.active>a:hover {
  background-color: initial;
  background-image: initial;
  color: #ffd100;
}

.bootstraps .navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-image: initial;
  box-shadow: initial;
}

.bootstraps .navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.bootstraps .navbar-ex1-collapse>.menu-mobile li {
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 6px;
}
.bootstraps .img-envio {
  margin-top: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 28px;
}

.bootstraps .left .bg-amarillo {
  background-color: #ffd100;
  right: 0;
  height: 61px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 0;
}

.bootstraps .right .bg-search {
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  height: 61px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.bootstraps #on-scroll {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 199;
  top: -150px;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s linear;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

.bootstraps #header-scroll #nav-scroll .navbar-brand {
  background: #1c1c1c;
  height: 60px !important;
  line-height: 30px !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  padding: 15px !important;
}


.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffd100;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .btn {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 17px;
  background-color: #ffd100;
  background-image: initial;
  border-color: #ffd100;
  text-shadow: inherit;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Univers';
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #333333;
  box-shadow: inherit;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 279px!important;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-radius: 21px;
  border: inherit;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  background-color: inherit;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .dropdown-menu i {
  float: right;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .dropdown-menu a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Univers'
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .dropdown-menu .fa.fa-map-marker {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #333333;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .dropdown-menu:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #F4F4F4;
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  right: 18px;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .select-caret {
  background-image: url(../images/iconos-svg/arrow-up.svg);
  width: 22px;
  height: 14px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .select-caret .active {
  background-image: url(../images/iconos-svg/arrow-down.svg);
  width: 22px;
  height: 14px;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-default:focus {
  background-color: #ffd100!important;
  border-color: inherit!important;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-default:hover {
  background-color: #ffd100!important;
  border-color: inherit!important;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .btn:hover {
  border: transparent;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .btn:focus {
  border: transparent;
}


/*input fixed buscado*/

.bootstraps .input-lg {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.bootstraps #btn-search {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.bootstraps #btn-search button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: inherit;
}

.bootstraps #btn-search input {
  border: inherit;
  box-shadow: inherit;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b3afaf;
  border-radius: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}

.bootstraps .geo-icono i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #333333;
}

.bootstraps #btn-search .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #333333;
}

.bootstraps #btn-search .form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #333333;
}

.bootstraps #btn-search .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* IE 10+ */
  color: #333333;
}

.bootstraps #btn-search .form-control:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #333333;
}

   .menu-fixed {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 66px;
}

.menu-fixed img {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll ul {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 23px;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll .dropdown-menu li {
  display: block;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll ul>.active>a {
  color: #ffd100;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll ul li a {
  padding: 0px 8px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffd100;
}


/*-------------------------------------------*/

.dropdown-menu {
  right: 0;
  left: inherit;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll .dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll .dropdown-menu a:hover {
  background: black;
  color: #ffd100;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll .dropdown-menu .btn-registrate-mobile {
  background-color: #ffd100;
  color: black;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll .dropdown-menu .btn-registrate-mobile a {
  background: #ffd100;
  color: black;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll .dropdown-menu .btn-registrate-mobile a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="bootstraps">
  <!-- BUSCADOR MENU SCROLL -->
  <section id="on-scroll" class="hidden-xs">
    <div class="container-fluid cerrar-buscador" style="padding: 0">
      <div class="container" id="scoll-search">
        <div class="row">


          <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2 col-md-3 right">
            <div class="bg-geo"></div>
            <div class="toggle-fixed">
              <ul class="switchList-fixed">
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="win-switch-fixed" id="c-fixed">
                  <label for="c-fixed"><span class="sw-fixed"></span><span class="small-fixed"></span></label>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <p>Geolocalización</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid menu-fixed sin-padding">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <a href=""><img src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v1/images/logo-fixed.svg" alt="logo pago facil"></a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 menu-scroll">
            <ul>
              <li class="active"><a href="">SERVICIOS</a></li>
              <li><a href="">¿QUÉ PUEDO PAGAR?</a></li>
              <li><a href="envio-dinero.html">ENVIO DE DINERO</a></li>
              <li><a href="novedades.html">NOVEDADES</a></li>
              <li><a href="contacto.html">CONTACTO</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">+</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">¿QUÉ ES PAGO FÁCIL?</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">PREGUNTAS FRECUENTES</a></li>
                  <li><a href="locales.html">SUMÁ TU LOCAL</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">SUMÁ TU EMPRESA</a></li>
                  <li class="btn-registrate-mobile"><a href="#">REGISTRATE</a></li>
                  <li class="btn-cuenta-mobile"><a href="#">MI CUENTA</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-search mostrar" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#fff;cursor: pointer;"></i></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- /BUSCADOR MENU SCROLL -->
  <!-- HEADER COMPLETO CON ROTADOR -->
  <header>
    <!-- MENU PRINCIPAL-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default hidden-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg" id="menu">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-3 sin-padding">
          <a href="index.html" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm visible-md visible-lg">
            <img class="img-responsive logo-header" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v1/images/logo-pf-header.svg" alt="logo de Pago Facil">
          </a>
          <a href="index.html" class="hidden-xs visible-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <img class="img-responsive logo-header" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v1/images/logo-fixed.svg" alt="logo de Pago Facil">
          </a>

          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-11 col-md-10 col-lg-9 sin-padding">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse sin-padding" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu-principal">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">SERVICIOS<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="">¿QUÉ PUEDO PAGAR?</a></li>
              <li><a href="">IMPRIMÍ TU FACTURA</a></li>
              <li><a href="envio-dinero.html">ENVIO DE DINERO</a></li>
              <li><a href="novedades.html">NOVEDADES</a></li>
              <li><a href="contacto.html">CONTACTO</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- /MENU PRINCIPAL-->

    <!-- ROTADOR PRINCIPAL-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="rotador">
      <div class="">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 sin-padding">
          <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v1/images/rotador-1.jpg" alt="imagen de la chica" style="width: 100%;">
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v1/images/rotador-1.jpg" alt="imagen de la chica" style="width: 100%;">
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v1/images/rotador-1.jpg" alt="imagen de la chica" style="width: 100%;">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="contenedor-buscador hidden-xs">
            <!--SELECTOR-->
            <div class="selector-desplegable">
              <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 sin-padding">
                <div id="custom-select-1" class="select-element" onclick="toggleActive()">
                  <span id="select-placeholder-1" class="selected-value">Dónde pagar</span>
                  <span class="select-caret"></span>
                </div>

             </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ROTADOR PRINCIPAL-->
  </header>
  <!-- /HEADER COMPLETO CON ROTADOR -->
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
  eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
  non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
  anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
  esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
  labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
  sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
  officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
  ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
  in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
  culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
  ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es que cuando el menú se mueva a -150px se le quite la clase `open` a ese submenú que aparece al pulsar el +. Esto sólo requeriría un pequeño cambio en tu JavaScript:

```
$(".menu-scroll li.open").removeClass("open");
```

Aquí lo puedes ver funcionando:

```js
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 360) {
    $("#on-scroll").css('top', '0');
  } else {
    $("#on-scroll").css('top', '-150px');
    $(".menu-scroll li.open").removeClass("open");
  }
});
```

```css
.bootstraps #menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 15px;
  z-index: 9;
  background-image: transparent;
}

.bootstraps .menu-principal {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-family: 'Univers';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  float: right;
}

.bootstraps .navbar-default .menu-principal a {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.bootstraps .navbar-default .menu-principal>li>a {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: initial;
}

.bootstraps .navbar-default .menu-principal>li>a:hover {
  color: #ffd100;
  text-shadow: initial;
}

.bootstraps .navbar-default .menu-principal>.active>a {
  background-color: initial;
  background-image: initial;
  box-shadow: initial;
  color: #ffd100;
}

.bootstraps .navbar-default .menu-principal>.active>a:hover {
  background-color: initial;
  background-image: initial;
  color: #ffd100;
}

.bootstraps .navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-image: initial;
  box-shadow: initial;
}

.bootstraps .navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.bootstraps .navbar-ex1-collapse>.menu-mobile li {
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 6px;
}
.bootstraps .img-envio {
  margin-top: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 28px;
}

.bootstraps .left .bg-amarillo {
  background-color: #ffd100;
  right: 0;
  height: 61px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 0;
}

.bootstraps .right .bg-search {
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  height: 61px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.bootstraps #on-scroll {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 199;
  top: -150px;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s linear;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
}

.bootstraps #header-scroll #nav-scroll .navbar-brand {
  background: #1c1c1c;
  height: 60px !important;
  line-height: 30px !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  padding: 15px !important;
}


.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffd100;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .btn {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 17px;
  background-color: #ffd100;
  background-image: initial;
  border-color: #ffd100;
  text-shadow: inherit;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Univers';
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #333333;
  box-shadow: inherit;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 279px!important;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-radius: 21px;
  border: inherit;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  background-color: inherit;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .dropdown-menu i {
  float: right;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .dropdown-menu a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Univers'
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .dropdown-menu .fa.fa-map-marker {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #333333;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .dropdown-menu:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #F4F4F4;
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  right: 18px;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .select-caret {
  background-image: url(../images/iconos-svg/arrow-up.svg);
  width: 22px;
  height: 14px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .select-caret .active {
  background-image: url(../images/iconos-svg/arrow-down.svg);
  width: 22px;
  height: 14px;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-default:focus {
  background-color: #ffd100!important;
  border-color: inherit!important;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-default:hover {
  background-color: #ffd100!important;
  border-color: inherit!important;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .btn:hover {
  border: transparent;
}

.bootstraps .btn-busqueda .btn-group .btn:focus {
  border: transparent;
}


/*input fixed buscado*/

.bootstraps .input-lg {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.bootstraps #btn-search {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

.bootstraps #btn-search button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: inherit;
}

.bootstraps #btn-search input {
  border: inherit;
  box-shadow: inherit;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b3afaf;
  border-radius: inherit;
  width: 100%;
}

.bootstraps .geo-icono i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #333333;
}

.bootstraps #btn-search .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  color: #333333;
}

.bootstraps #btn-search .form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #333333;
}

.bootstraps #btn-search .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  /* IE 10+ */
  color: #333333;
}

.bootstraps #btn-search .form-control:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #333333;
}

   .menu-fixed {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 66px;
}

.menu-fixed img {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll ul {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 23px;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll .dropdown-menu li {
  display: block;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll ul>.active>a {
  color: #ffd100;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll ul li a {
  padding: 0px 8px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll ul li a:hover {
  color: #ffd100;
}


/*-------------------------------------------*/

.dropdown-menu {
  right: 0;
  left: inherit;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll .dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 5px 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll .dropdown-menu a:hover {
  background: black;
  color: #ffd100;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll .dropdown-menu .btn-registrate-mobile {
  background-color: #ffd100;
  color: black;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll .dropdown-menu .btn-registrate-mobile a {
  background: #ffd100;
  color: black;
}

.menu-fixed .menu-scroll .dropdown-menu .btn-registrate-mobile a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="bootstraps">
  <!-- BUSCADOR MENU SCROLL -->
  <section id="on-scroll" class="hidden-xs">
    <div class="container-fluid cerrar-buscador" style="padding: 0">
      <div class="container" id="scoll-search">
        <div class="row">


          <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2 col-md-3 right">
            <div class="bg-geo"></div>
            <div class="toggle-fixed">
              <ul class="switchList-fixed">
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="win-switch-fixed" id="c-fixed">
                  <label for="c-fixed"><span class="sw-fixed"></span><span class="small-fixed"></span></label>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <p>Geolocalización</p>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid menu-fixed sin-padding">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
            <a href=""><img src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v1/images/logo-fixed.svg" alt="logo pago facil"></a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 menu-scroll">
            <ul>
              <li class="active"><a href="">SERVICIOS</a></li>
              <li><a href="">¿QUÉ PUEDO PAGAR?</a></li>
              <li><a href="envio-dinero.html">ENVIO DE DINERO</a></li>
              <li><a href="novedades.html">NOVEDADES</a></li>
              <li><a href="contacto.html">CONTACTO</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">+</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">¿QUÉ ES PAGO FÁCIL?</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">PREGUNTAS FRECUENTES</a></li>
                  <li><a href="locales.html">SUMÁ TU LOCAL</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">SUMÁ TU EMPRESA</a></li>
                  <li class="btn-registrate-mobile"><a href="#">REGISTRATE</a></li>
                  <li class="btn-cuenta-mobile"><a href="#">MI CUENTA</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-search mostrar" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#fff;cursor: pointer;"></i></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- /BUSCADOR MENU SCROLL -->
  <!-- HEADER COMPLETO CON ROTADOR -->
  <header>
    <!-- MENU PRINCIPAL-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default hidden-xs visible-sm visible-md visible-lg" id="menu">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-3 sin-padding">
          <a href="index.html" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm visible-md visible-lg">
            <img class="img-responsive logo-header" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v1/images/logo-pf-header.svg" alt="logo de Pago Facil">
          </a>
          <a href="index.html" class="hidden-xs visible-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <img class="img-responsive logo-header" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v1/images/logo-fixed.svg" alt="logo de Pago Facil">
          </a>

          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-11 col-md-10 col-lg-9 sin-padding">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse sin-padding" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu-principal">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">SERVICIOS<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="">¿QUÉ PUEDO PAGAR?</a></li>
              <li><a href="">IMPRIMÍ TU FACTURA</a></li>
              <li><a href="envio-dinero.html">ENVIO DE DINERO</a></li>
              <li><a href="novedades.html">NOVEDADES</a></li>
              <li><a href="contacto.html">CONTACTO</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- /MENU PRINCIPAL-->

    <!-- ROTADOR PRINCIPAL-->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="rotador">
      <div class="">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 sin-padding">
          <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v1/images/rotador-1.jpg" alt="imagen de la chica" style="width: 100%;">
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v1/images/rotador-1.jpg" alt="imagen de la chica" style="width: 100%;">
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://qkstudiodemo.com/pagofacil/v1/images/rotador-1.jpg" alt="imagen de la chica" style="width: 100%;">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="contenedor-buscador hidden-xs">
            <!--SELECTOR-->
            <div class="selector-desplegable">
              <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4 sin-padding">
                <div id="custom-select-1" class="select-element" onclick="toggleActive()">
                  <span id="select-placeholder-1" class="selected-value">Dónde pagar</span>
                  <span class="select-caret"></span>
                </div>

             </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ROTADOR PRINCIPAL-->
  </header>
  <!-- /HEADER COMPLETO CON ROTADOR -->
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
  eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
  non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
  anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
  esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
  labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
  sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
  quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui
  officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
  ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum
  dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
  in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
  incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
  culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
  ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

</div>
```

Comment: Perfecto alvaro! claro si era lo que queria, que cuando subas se vaya solo. Muchas gracias!